# Can not find the symbol R in running androidTests

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I am trying to clone and run this project.
[Catroid](https://github.com/Catrobat/Catroid)
I am unable to run the tests inside androidTests.
I have previously written tests for my project, but I can't seem to understand the problem with this one.
The steps I am following are:-

1. Cloning the repository.
2. Opening it in android studio,The app is running completely fine.
3. But when I try to run the tests(androidTests), It gives following errors:

   ```
    Error:Can Not find the symbol R

    Error:package R does not exist,and gives 72 such errors
   ```

One of those lines which is causing this error is this
[Error Line](https://github.com/Catrobat/Catroid/blob/bc0b9421a63b84e42bbab7443f4c5af3b1378a59/catroid/src/androidTest/java/org/catrobat/catroid/test/content/actions/PlaySoundActionTest.java#L38)

I have manually checked, R.java file for test resources is there in the project

This is the google group thread of the same
[Google Group Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/catrobat/-Kkk8k5BBKk)

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, invalidating the cache, restarting.

I dont know what i am missing
[ScreenShot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caGah.png).

Comment: it seems like, from their own github, that their tests ARE failing https://jenkins.catrob.at/job/Catroid/job/develop/1277/

Comment: That's not always the case, Look at this pull req https://jenkins.catrob.at/job/Catroid/job/PR-3519/2/